# |DataDirectory| for EF Update-Database

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

How to define |DataDirectory| for WPF project that is in Connection String for EF command "Update-Migration"? There are a lot solutions to add : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", ***);
but it works only if application runs. I do not run application  - just want to create and migrate Database

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question, may be this some uncommon behavior, but best, what i found - it is specify connection string parameter for update-database command:

```
update-database -ConnectionString "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient
```