# Updata-Database -ConnectionStringName with modified |DataDirectory|

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I want to use EF-Migrations and therefore have to use Update-Database. Since I use a few .mdf-files in the main folder of the project that also should be used while debugging, I have a few `ConnectionStrings` in `App.config` I use with EF.

A sample `ConnectionString`:

```
<add name="DataContext"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Database;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf"/>
```

Because while debugging `|DataDirectory|` is `Project-Root\bin\Debug` I wrote a function that changes `|DataDirectory|` to `Project-Root\app_data`:

```
        #if DEBUG
        string path = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent?.FullName + "\\app_data";
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
        #endif
```

The problem is that `|DataDirectory|` does not get updated when I call `Update-Database` and therefore can not find the .mdf-file.

I found a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436317/datadirectory-for-ef-update-database) with no answers/solutions, but it did not seem to get that much attention.

So is there a clean way of handling this or a better one to do this in the first place? I do need the Project to be easily portable, meaning that I have to be able to just copy the folder and have another VS instance run it.

Answer (score 1):

The `|DataDirectory|` concept is more for web projects and considering `Debug` is running under `Project-Root\bin\Debug`, then I guess your application isn't a web application.

The simplest answer would be to just set the `.mdf` file to `Copy if newer` or `Always copy` in your project. That way you'll always get the `.mdf` file inside the right folder when you execute the application from `VS`.

Comment: At this point I am still trying around but this will eventually be a web project. I did not know that `|DataDirectory|` was only supposed for these.
But I understand correctly that a web Project wouldn't run under `Project-Root\bin\Debug`, yeah?

Comment: Web projects support the |DataDirectoy| "out-of-the-box" using the `App_Data` folder, while other projects require some maneuvering (as you did with `AppDomain`). As far as I remember, some parts of a web app still run from the `bin\[debug|release]` fodlers.
You can read more on the `App_Data` folder here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478948.aspx
Just look for "App_Data" in that page.